# Ruby get download progression

Tags: ruby, download, progress

How do I download a file from a link but also get the download progress in order to display it ?

From the very little I know open-uri and the typhoeus gem ( I use both ) manage the download internaly and I have no idea on how to get the download progression from them.

I suppose what I am looking for is a way of pausing the download and get the progress of update a value each time a packet is received but I do not know how to proceed.

I could also use an other gem ? If yes, which one and why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do it as a chunked request, which is what libraries like open-uri do behind the scenes if you use their high level APIs (like `open(uri).read`).

Untested example based on https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/170237:

```
u = URI.parse(uri)
s = ""
progress = 0

Net::HTTP.start(u.host, u.port) do |http|
  http.request_get(u.path) do |response|
    response.read_body do |chunk|
      s << chunk
      progress += chunk.length
      puts "Downloaded #{progress} so far"
    end
  end
end
puts "Received:\n#{s}"
```